# How to hide this specific div element using css for each page (WP)

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

First post here (yay!), I am looking for help as I am fighting with this stuff since today's morning. I tried to use some CSS awkwardly before, but it did not seem to work.

So, I am trying to remove this cart icon/button ( in the lower-right corner for visitors that are not logged in. (www.friendly.marketing)

The code of that element is

```
</header>         
     <div id="dark-cart-overlayer"></div>
 <div id="cart-panel">
    <div id="cart-panel-trigger">
        <span class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></span>
        <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
            <path fill="#ffffff" d="M10.707 10.5l5.646-5.646c0.195-0.195 0.195-0.512 0-0.707s-0.512-0.195-0.707 0l-5.646 5.646-5.646-5.646c-0.195-0.195-0.512-0.195-0.707 0s-0.195 0.512 0 0.707l5.646 5.646-5.646 5.646c-0.195 0.195-0.195 0.512 0 0.707 0.098 0.098 0.226 0.146 0.354 0.146s0.256-0.049 0.354-0.146l5.646-5.646 5.646 5.646c0.098 0.098 0.226 0.146 0.354 0.146s0.256-0.049 0.354-0.146c0.195-0.195 0.195-0.512 0-0.707l-5.646-5.646z"></path>
        </svg>
    </div>
```

Is there any way I can achieve it in css?

Comment: span.fa-shopping-cart{display:none} ?

Comment: Thank you for a reply, unfortunately, it does not hide the button, just an icon. It also hides an icon for a logged-in customer as well. All the mechanisms I seen before are not working for me, I guess I am poor css guy.

Comment: here is another topic regarding similar issue, you might find it helpfull https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/181630/change-css-when-user-is-logged-in

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
cart-panel{display:none;}
```

It would hide div Id with cart-panel.

Comment: It does not hide it at all, I checked multiple combinations in a real time.

Comment: can you share your site URL and highlight the part that you want to hide

Comment: Yes, it is www.friendly.marketing, and the cart icon (plus its black background) in the lower-right corner.

Comment: i cannot see any cart icon in the footer or header with as you have mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
div#cart-panel-trigger { display: none; }
```

I hope this works out.

Comment: This one is perfect, thank you very much. Now I guess I need to find some code about "if logged in then show" etc. Many Thanks :)

Comment: I suggest wrapping the code in code block formatting for easy readability.

Comment: Good idea, newcomer mistake :)) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

WordPress has the class `.logged-in` put in place on the `<body>` tag to identify if a user is logged in or not.

In your css define your style like this:

```
body.logged-in #cart-panel-trigger {
  display: none;
}
#cart-panel-trigger {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd need some kind of conditional logic to determine if the user is logged in.  You can use WooCommerce hooks to hide the add to cart button.  This code should achieve that.  You'd need to add it to your child theme's `functions.php`.

```
add_action( 'init', 'hide_add_to_cart_not_logged_in' );

function hide_add_to_cart_not_logged_in() { 
 if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {       
  remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
  remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
  add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'print_login_to_see', 11 ); 
  add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'print_login_to_see', 31 );
}
}

function print_login_to_see() {
echo '<a href="' . get_permalink(wc_get_page_id('myaccount')) . '">' . __('Login to add to cart', 'theme_name') . '</a>';
}
```